# How to find greatest number

Tags: java, arrays

How to compute the greatest number and display it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GreatestNumber {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] num = new int [10];
    int counter;
    int max = 0;

    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter StaffID to be edited:");
        num[i]=read.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format code correctly, and tag the question as Java.

Comment: @apomene A binary search finds the location of a value within a sorted array. That's not what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @apomene Binary search works for sorted arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to compare the numbers as you're reading them. Also, using `0` as a starting value for `max` will not print out the results you want if all input values are negative. Use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead:

```
int [] num = new int [10];
int counter;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // <-- initial value

Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter StaffID to be edited:");
    num[i] = read.nextInt();
    if (num[i] > max)
    {
        max = num[i];
    }
}

System.out.print("Max number is:");
System.out.print(max);
```

Comment: This won't work if the maximum number is negative, it's better to set the maximum to `num[0]`

Comment: It's `Integer.MIN_VALUE` not `int.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: You're also printing out `x` instead of `max` in the end there :P

Answer (score 3):

Beside the solution provided by other users, you can make a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) from the Array and then use an already existing method that finds the maximum value in the list.

```
List list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(num));
System.out.println(Collections.max(list)); //Will print the maximum value
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it:

1. Since you are after the largest number, create an integer which has a very small value.
2. Iterate over the elements of your array. If the element you are currently looking at is larger than the current largest element (initialized in step 1), then update the value of the largest element.

Answer (score 0):

keep track of the current max and update it if you find a higher number, ie

```
if (num[i] > max)
  max = num[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a running variable `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Compare it in a loop with every element in the array, and if the array element is bigger, copy its value to `max`. In the end you have the biggest element in `max`.